# Bug-sized halberd?

Tags: weapons, medieval, insects

I'm constructing a world where insects battle using medieval and fantasy weapons. I'm trying to think of an object that could be used by a bug as a [halberd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halberd) - that is, part spear, part axe. For example, in the analogous world of [`Hollow Knight`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_Knight) the protagonist has a nail for a sword.

Preferably, this object should be a noun (e.g. "an XXXX" rather than "a piece of YYYY"), small enough for a bug or tiny critter to wield, and possibly man-made.

So far all I can think of is a toothpick - but this would only serve the function of a spear, not also a cutting axe.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Scalpel is the closest thing I can think of.

Comment: bug sized is fairly vague do you have a more concrete measurement. my suggestion would be to look at engraving, sculpting, or dental tools, especially those with removable tips.

Comment: What scale are we talking here? "Bugs" could mean anything from near-microscopic to as big as your hand. One concern is that materials do not behave the same at smaller scale. A spear would likely work equivalently, but hammers will not have the mass to get through chitinous material with any meaningful effect. Cutting edges will likely not be effective like blades did not work against the full plate harnesses of the renaissance.

Comment: Good comments RE: scale. I was intentionally ambiguous - by 'bug' I could mean something as small as a sand midge or a flea to as large as a small rodent - I'm allowing a bit of liberal interpretation in terms of the sizes of bugs compared to the real world :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seam ripper. For insect military use rather than sewing I would remove both the handle and the protective tip on the shorter point.

It is possible some readers of this site have not done any sewing. A seam ripper is backspace-delete for sewing. The long point is inserted into the stitches, which then get cut by the sharp edge of the curve.

[image]

Comment: There are so many great suggestions here - but I think this one is my favourite! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

One choice is to use building materials.  Most will be iseful as a spear or stabby sort of weapon.  But, a few have useful features, like Picture hangers could be a spear with a shield

[image]

The one source is replicas used for doll houses of any size.  Like this a 2”  halberd

[image]

Then there are unusual gewgaws like key fobs and lapel pins.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Would a clipped human fingernail glued to the toothpick work? It is the only small thing I can come up with that has a curved edge. Most animals have pointy claws, but humans have an edge.

Answer (score 2):

**Hypodermic needle.**

**[image: Hypodermic needle.]**

https://www.caretouchusa.com/product/hypodermic-needle-27gx1-1-2-100ct/

Hypodermic needles are pointed but also the bevelled edge is sharpened into 2 blades.  You can cut with them.  For this reason hypodermic needles are unsurpassed for removing splinters.

The point plus the two blades makes the halberd you are seeking.